# Multiple conditions without using boolean operators in Scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I don't know how to ask this question. Basically, my professor solved a problem where he didn't use boolean expression (and, or, not) in the cond statement. So, I tried to come up with a dummy example and I noticed something peculiar. As you can see below. I don't know why true false gives me false instead of going go to the else statement, but when I do false true, it goes to the else statement. I am treating this as an AND operator and I know I am wrong.

```
(cond ((= 2 2) (= 3 3))
      (else "Hello"))   ; --> T T --> #t

(cond ((= 2 2) (= 3 1))
      (else "Hello"))   ; --> T F --> #f

(cond ((= 2 1) (= 3 3))
      (else "Hello"))   ; --> F T --> "Hello"

(cond ((= 2 1) (= 3 1))
      (else "Hello"))   ; --> F F --> "Hello"
```

Comment: The car of each clause is a condition and everything else is what is executed if this condition holds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three equations that you should know.

1.

```
(cond
  [#t <A>]
  .........)
```

evaluates to `<A>`.

2.

```
(cond
  [#f <A>]
  .........)
```

evaluates to

```
(cond
  .........)
```

That is, when the LHS of a clause is `#f`, just "cross out" that clause.

3.

```
(cond
  [else <A>])
```

evaluates to `<A>`.

In your examples:

1.

```
(cond ((= 2 2) (= 3 3))
      (else "Hello"))
```

=

```
(cond (#t (= 3 3))
      (else "Hello"))
```

By using the first equation, we get that the result should be `(= 3 3)` = `#t`.

2.

```
(cond ((= 2 2) (= 3 1))
      (else "Hello"))
```

=

```
(cond (#t (= 3 1))
      (else "Hello"))
```

By using the first equation, we get that the result should be `(= 3 1)` = `#f`.

3.

```
(cond ((= 2 1) (= 3 3))
      (else "Hello"))
```

=

```
(cond (#f (= 3 3))
      (else "Hello"))
```

By using the second equation, we get that it should evaluate to:

```
(cond (else "Hello"))
```

By using the third equation, we get that it should evaluate to `"Hello"`.

4.

```
(cond ((= 2 1) (= 3 1))
      (else "Hello"))
```

=

```
(cond (#f (= 3 1))
      (else "Hello"))
```

By using the second equation, we get that it should evaluate to:

```
(cond (else "Hello"))
```

By using the third equation, we get that it should evaluate to `"Hello"`.

Answer (score 1):

The `cond` syntax is

```
(cond (condition1 value1)
      (condition2 value2)
      ...
      (conditionN valueN))
```

So your conditions are `(= 2 2)`, `(= 2 1)`, and `else` (which is equivalent to `#t` in a `cond`-expression), and the possible values are `(= 3 3)`, `(= 3 1)`, and `"Hello".

And

```
(cond (condition value1) 
      (else value2))
```

is equivalent to

```
(if condition value1 value2)
```

so you have the equivalent of

```
(if (= 2 2)
    (= 3 3)
    "Hello")

(if (= 2 2)
    (= 3 1)
    "Hello")
```

and so on.